# Como copiar o conteudo de dois arquivos em um terceiro arquivo em c?

Tags: c, arquivo

Eu preciso criar um arquivo que seja a copia do conteudo de outros dois arquivos (ja existentes), o usuario ira digitar o nome desses dois arquivos.
No meu caso, o primeiro arquivo contém: "oi, banana, queijo", e o segundo:"geleia, sorvete".Aparentemente o programa roda muito bem, e ele consegue ler o que tem nos arquivos 1 e 2 mas quando eu vou checar no terceiro arquivo (que deveria ser a copia do arquivo 1 + o arquivo 2), só aparece um simbolo quadrado. A unica explicação de como fazer esse codigo que achei ensinava ler todo o arquivo 1 e guardar em uma certa variavel, depois por meio de um `fputs` inserir o conteudo da variavel no arquivo destinatario, no video aula que eu vi tudo funcionou muito bem, e foi o que eu fiz, mas ão deu certo.

Segue o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *arqum;
    FILE *arqdois;
    FILE *arqtres;
    char ch,ch1,leitor[100],leitor2[100];
    char nome1[20],nome2[20];

    printf("\nDigite o nome primeiro arquivo:\n");
    gets(nome1);

    arqum=fopen(nome1, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura
    if(NULL==arqum)
    {
        printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
        system("Pause");
        exit (1);
    }
    ch=fgetc(arqum);
    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(ch);
        ch=fgetc(arqum);
    }
    fclose (arqum);

    printf("\nDigite o nome do segundo arquivo:\n");
    gets(nome2);

    arqdois=fopen(nome2, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura
    if(NULL==arqum)
    {
        printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
        system("Pause");
        exit (1);
    }
    ch1=fgetc(arqum);
    while(ch1!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(ch1);
        ch1=fgetc(arqdois);
    }
    fclose (arqdois);

    arqtres=fopen("arquivotres.txt","a+");
    if(NULL==arqtres)
    {
        printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
        system("Pause");
        exit (1);
    }

    while(fgets(leitor,100,arqum)!=NULL);
    fputs(leitor,arqtres);
    fclose(arqtres);

    arqtres=fopen("arquivotres.txt","a+");
    while(fgets(leitor2,100,arqdois)!=NULL);
    fputs(leitor2,arqtres);
    fclose(arqtres);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, sou iniciante em programação e estou aprendendo a programar em C. A dias atrás aprendi sobre arquivos (de fato ainda estou aprendendo).
O seu código funcionando corretamente é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *arqum;
  FILE *arqdois;
  FILE *arqtres;
  char ch,ch1,leitor[100],leitor2[100];
  char nome1[20],nome2[20];

  printf("\nDigite o nome primeiro arquivo:\n");
  gets(nome1);

  arqum=fopen(nome1, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura
  if(NULL==arqum)
  {
      printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
      system("Pause");
      exit (1);
  }
  ch=fgetc(arqum);
  while(ch!=EOF)
  {
      putchar(ch);
      ch=fgetc(arqum);
  }
  fclose (arqum);

  printf("\nDigite o nome do segundo arquivo:\n");
  gets(nome2);

  arqdois=fopen(nome2, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura
  if(NULL==arqum)
  {
      printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
      system("Pause");
      exit (1);
  }
  ch1=fgetc(arqum);
  while(ch1!=EOF)
  {
      putchar(ch1);
      ch1=fgetc(arqdois);
  }
  fclose (arqdois);

  arqtres=fopen("arquivotres.txt","a+");
  if(NULL==arqtres)
  {
      printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
      system("Pause");
      exit (1);
  }

  arqum=fopen(nome1, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura DE NOVO
  if(NULL==arqum)
  {
      printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
      system("Pause");
      exit (1);
  }

  while(fgets(leitor,100,arqum)!=NULL);
  fputs(leitor,arqtres);
  fclose(arqtres);
  fclose (arqum); // fecha arquivo um

  arqdois=fopen(nome2, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura DE NOVO
  if(NULL==arqudois)
  {
      printf("O arquivo não pode ser aberto. \n" );
      system("Pause");
      exit (1);
  }

  arqtres=fopen("arquivotres.txt","a+");
  while(fgets(leitor2,100,arqdois)!=NULL);
  fputs(leitor2,arqtres);

  fclose (arqdois); // fecha arquivo dois
  fclose(arqtres);
return 0;
}
```

A solução para o seu problema era que o `arqum` e o `arqdois`estavam fechados na hora hora que você estava passando o `leitor` e o `leitor2`para o `arqtres`, ou seja, você estava usando o `arqum` e o `arqdois` para abrirem os arquivos respectivos solicitados pelo usuário.
Deste modo, eles serviam de apontadores para os arquivos que o usuário solicitava para ler e e como você fechou os mesmos, não dava certo a passagem das strings lidas para o `arqtres`.
Então *abri-los* (não sei se essa é a sintaxe correta do Português kkk) de novo. Você pode ver nas linhas

```
arqum=fopen(nome1, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura DE NOVO
```

e

```
arqdois=fopen(nome2, "r"); //abre o arquivo para leitura DE NOVO
```

e depois fui fechando depois do uso.
É isso. Espero que tenha entendido.